# Insert into table avoiding hard coding of column names using spring

Tags: sql, spring, jdbctemplate

Is there a way to avoid hard coding of all column names and values with '?' marks using spring ?
instead of writing my insert statement as `insert into TABLE_NAME (x, y, z) values(?,?,?)` as I have many fields to set, not just 3. I want something like this `insert into TABLE_NAME (myobject)`. 
This object will have column name and column value. I want to use beanpropertuyrowmapper to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using JPA like kds said I don't think you are going to get rid of hard-coding the column names. An option is to create them as CONSTANTs in your class and concatenate them to your String queries if you are using the same columns in multiple queries. That would allow you to only have to update the column names in one place in case they did happen to change often.
If you are looking just to get rid of the "?" you can always use Springs JDBC named parameter queries. For example,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (X, Y, Z)
VALUES (:xParam, :yParam, :zParam)
```

In your method you would add those values to a Map as such,

```
final SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource.addValue("xParam", X.getName).addValue("yParam", Y.getName).addValue("zParam", Z.getName);
```

And then you would make a call using Springs [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) using the query and namedparameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Spring JPA Data + Hibernate. Then you can persist the data easily.

Take a look at [Accessing Data with JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

If you really need to use the `beanpropertuyrowmapper` then take a look at [Spring JdbcTemplate Querying Examples](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-jdbctemplate-querying-examples/)

Comment: yeah. that is there for selecting. Can't i use it to insert too? Is there any way i can use it to insert also?